# What to use instead of FirstOrDefault to get the json text associated with the chosen chapter in C# using linq?

Tags: c#, json, linq

I have a program where the user has to get the text from json based on the chapter clicked within the protocol by the listview item (the chapters)

How do i fix this?

**Here the user selects the chosen chapter within the protocol**

```
    //for chosen step inside protocol
    public void Handle_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
    {
        //change title based on clicked step
        var tappedStep = (Content)MyListView.SelectedItem;
        var nextTitle = Title + " - " + tappedStep.ChapterTitle;
        Navigation.PushAsync(new StepView(_protocol, Title, tappedStep.ChapterTitle));
        //Deselect item
        ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null;
    }
```

What goes wrong next is that the label text is ALWAYS the first text of the very first chapter this is because I use FirstOrDefault in the next class `StepView.cs` the logic here will have to be such that it takes the text that belongs to the corresponding chapter! Instead of the very first one within the protocol.

```
public partial class StepView : ContentPage
{
    //get step
    private Protocol _protocol;

    //go to selected step
    public StepView(Protocol protocol, string title, string chapterTitle)
    {
        _protocol = protocol;
        InitializeComponent();
        Title = title + " - " + chapterTitle;
        // get label text
        lblText.Text = protocol.Contents.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ChapterTitle == chapterTitle).Text;
    }

    private int index;

    public void BtnBack_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        index--;
        var firstId = _protocol.Contents.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Contentid != null).Contentid;
        BtnNext.IsEnabled = true;
        if (index == firstId - 1)
        {
            BtnBack.IsEnabled = false;
        }
        var content = _protocol.Contents.ElementAtOrDefault(index);
        lblText.Text = content?.Text;
        //get current navTitle on button click
        getNewNavTitle(content);
    }

    public void BtnNext_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        index++;
        BtnBack.IsEnabled = true;
        if (index == _protocol.Contents.Count - 1)
        {
            BtnNext.IsEnabled = false;
        }
        var content = _protocol.Contents.ElementAtOrDefault(index);
        lblText.Text = content?.Text;
        //get current navTitle on button click
        getNewNavTitle(content);
    }

    //get new protocol + chapter based on btnBack and btnNext
    private void getNewNavTitle(Content content)
    {
        Title = null;
        string nextTitile = _protocol.Name + " - " + content.NavTitle;
        Title = nextTitile;
    }

    //go back to home
    public void btnHome_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //go to mainpage
        Navigation.PushAsync(new MainPage());
    }
```

**This is the json I use**

```
{
  "protocols": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Pols meten",
      "contents": [
        {
          "contentid": "1",
          "chapterTitle": "Voorzorg",
          "text": "voor blabla"
        },
        {
          "contentid": "2",
          "text": "voor blabla2"
        },
        {
          "contentid": "3",
          "text": "voor blablabla3"
        },
        {
          "contentid": "4",
          "chapterTitle": "Handeling",
    }
  ]
}
```

**And this are my Domain Classes**

```
public partial class RootObject
{
    [JsonProperty("protocols")]
    public List<Protocol> Protocols { get; set; }
}

public partial class Protocol
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("contents")]
    public List<Content> Contents { get; set; }
}

public partial class Content
{
    [JsonProperty("contentid")]
    public long Contentid { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("chapterTitle", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string ChapterTitle { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("text")]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

How can I make the label text, instead of FirstOrDefault, the text that belongs to the beginning of the selected chapter?

Comment: Please don't edit the question with the answer you were given. The question stands as it is, and if you rewrite it the accepted answer stops making sense to future readers. If you have subsequent questions, create a new question, don't edit the original.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using [this version of `FirstOrDefault`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_FirstOrDefault__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Boolean__), which says the following:

> Returns the first element of the sequence that satisfies a condition or a default value if no such element is found.

In this case, the condition you're specifying (or "predicate") is this:

```
x => x.Text != null
```

This just says "return `true` if the `Text` property is not `null`" -- which will always return `true` for the "very first item" (based on the data you've proved), as you mentioned.

Instead, you probably want your predicate to return `true` only for the item with the appropriate `ChapterTitle`.

Start by changing `Handle_ItemTapped` from this:

```
Navigation.PushAsync(new StepView(_protocol, nextTitle));
```

To this (this is because we need the value of `tappedStep.ChapterTitle` in the `StepView` constructor for the new predicate):

```
Navigation.PushAsync(new StepView(_protocol, Title, tappedStep.ChapterTitle));
```

Then update the constructor for `StepView` to this:

```
public StepView(Protocol protocol, string title, string chapterTitle)
{
    _protocol = protocol;
    InitializeComponent();
    Title = title + " - " + chapterTitle;
    // get label text
    lblText.Text = protocol.Contents.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ChapterTitle == chapterTitle).Text;
}
```

Now, the predicate for `FirstOrDefault` is:

```
x => x.ChapterTitle == chapterTitle
```

Which means "return `true` if the `ChapterTitle` property is equal to `chapterTitle`".

Also note that setting the `Title` property is slightly different from your original code, you may need to adjust this to get the exact functionality you're looking for.

Comment: I tried your code but i got `The name 'step' does not exist in the current context` in `handle_tapped` @Donut

Comment: where should i use `x => x.Text != null`

Comment: Ah, it looks like it should be tappedStep.

Comment: i fixed it but now  i got `System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` on  `lblText.Text = protocol.Contents.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Text == chapterTitle).Text;` @Donut

Comment: what should i use then to get the content in the label based on the chapter

Comment: That means that `protocol.Contents.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Text == chapterTitle)` returned `null`, and the error happens when accessing the `Text` property. What's the value of `chapterTitle`? I thought that based on your question it would match the values in `protocols`.

Comment: the chapterTitle is the value that is tapped (that's correct) but on the stepview page i need to see the text based on the chapter

Comment: What i want based on my json is if the user tapped: Voorzorg the label text = voor blabla and so on

Comment: based on the tapped chapter

Comment: how should i fix this

Comment: @Teun Ah, I had a mistake in my answer - use this for your predicate: `x => x.ChapterTitle == chapterTitle`. I had forgotten to change `x.Text` (from the original question) to `x.ChapterTitle`

Comment: it almost works, the only problem is that when i click on the 2nd chapter and then click on the continue button i get the text with id 2 from the first chapter instead of the following. I have updated my code for this in my answer see next and back button in stepview.cs @donut

Comment: @Teun You may need to post a new question; see @Flater's comment - we've fixed the `FirstOrDefault` predicate, which was the original problem.

Comment: but what should i did wrong with the buttons then? this problem started when i fixed the firstordefault problem

Comment: @Teun Again, this is a separate problem from the original question - please post a new question with a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Made a new question can you give it a look? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69915718/buttons-dont-count-chapter-ids-correctly-from-json-using-linq-in-c-sharp @Donut